# How to use two if statements in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, console

This is my code for an ATM, but somehow when I press the number 2 on the numpad I get my `else` statement that there was no choice for this number.

```cs
Console.WriteLine("What is your name? ");
string userName = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("You are: " + userName);
Console.WriteLine("How much money do you have? ");
string Balance = Console.ReadLine();
float startBalance = float.Parse(Balance);

Console.WriteLine(userName + ", your balance is " + startBalance + " EUR");
Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for WITHDRAWAL");
Console.WriteLine("Press 2 for DEPOSIT");


if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.NumPad1)
{
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("How much money do you wish to withdraw? ");
    string Withdrawal = Console.ReadLine();
    float wBalance = float.Parse(Withdrawal);

    Console.WriteLine("Your new balance is " + (startBalance - wBalance) + " EUR");
    Console.ReadLine();
    Environment.Exit(0);

} 



if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.NumPad2)
{
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("How much money do you wish to deposit? ");
    string Deposit = Console.ReadLine();
    float dBalance = float.Parse(Deposit);

    Console.WriteLine("Your new balance is " + (startBalance - dBalance) + " EUR");
    Console.ReadLine();
    Environment.Exit(0);

}

else Console.WriteLine("There was no choice for this number");
```

Comment: Did you step through this with the debugger?

Comment: When you have this code working, take it to codereview stackexchange - there's a lot that could be improved here to make it cleaner.  If you get into good habits now it will help later.

Comment: Wish my bank asked me how much money I had before giving me the Withdrawal option! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy + Paste is *evil*: please, note that *subtracting* (*adding* expected) deposit

```
"Your new balance is " + (startBalance - dBalance) + " EUR"
```

is a *typical* copy + paste *error*.

Instead of *copying yourself*, let's *extract a method*:

```
private static float ReadFloat(string title) {
  // keep asking user...
  while (true) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
      Console.WriteLine(title);

    if (!float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out float result))
      Console.WriteLine("Syntax error. Please, try again.");
    else if (result < 0)
      Console.WriteLine("Negative sum is not allowed. Please, try again.");
    else
      return result; // ... until valid value is provided
  }
}
```

Then use it

```
...

Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for WITHDRAWAL");
Console.WriteLine("Press 2 for DEPOSIT");

// Ask user once - Console.ReadKey().Key - then operate with his/her choice 
var choice = Console.ReadKey().Key;

// balance change (either negative - withdraw or positive - deposit)
float delta = 
    choice == ConsoleKey.NumPad1 ? -ReadFloat("How much money do you wish to withdraw?")
  : choice == ConsoleKey.NumPad2 ?  ReadFloat("How much money do you wish to deposit?")
  : 0f;

if (delta != 0) {
  Console.WriteLine($"Your new balance is {startBalance + delta} EUR");
  Console.ReadLine();
  Environment.Exit(0);
}
else 
  Console.WriteLine("There was no choice for this number");
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two separate `if`s and two separate calls to `Console.ReadKey()`.

Instead, extract that call into a variable, and use an if-else if-else sequence to evaluate it:

```cs
ConsoleKeyInfo.Key key = onsole.ReadKey().Key;

if (key == ConsoleKey.NumPad1)
{
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("How much money do you wish to withdraw? ");
    string Withdrawal = Console.ReadLine();
    float wBalance = float.Parse(Withdrawal);

    Console.WriteLine("Your new balance is " + (startBalance - wBalance) + " EUR");
    Console.ReadLine();
    Environment.Exit(0);
} 
else if (key == ConsoleKey.NumPad2)
{
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("How much money do you wish to deposit? ");
    string Deposit = Console.ReadLine();
    float dBalance = float.Parse(Deposit);

    Console.WriteLine("Your new balance is " + (startBalance - dBalance) + " EUR");
    Console.ReadLine();
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
else 
{
    Console.WriteLine("There was no choice for this number");
}
```